# kubernetes minikube start issue with virtualbox in windows-7

Tags: docker, windows-7, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

Environment:
I have Windows-7 machine. I have installed Docker Toolbox (which installed Oracle Virtual Box version: 5.2.8r121009)

```
C:\Users>VBoxManage -version
5.2.8r121009
```

When I launch virtual box and check version of linux using command: cat /proc/version

```
Linux version 4.9.93-boot2docker (root@eb591e1ad697) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Thu May 10 16:27:54 UTC 2018
```

Minikube version (use minikube version):v0.28.0

OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release):

```
NAME=Boot2Docker
VERSION=18.05.0-ce
ID=boot2docker
ID_LIKE=tcl
VERSION_ID=18.05.0-ce
PRETTY_NAME="Boot2Docker 18.05.0-ce (TCL 8.2.1); HEAD : b5d6989 - Thu May 10 16:35:28 UTC 2018"
ANSI_COLOR="1;34"
HOME_URL="http://boot2docker.io"
SUPPORT_URL="https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues"
```

VM Driver (e.g. cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json | grep DriverName): No such file or directory

ISO version (e.g. cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json | grep -i ISO or minikube ssh cat /etc/VERSION): No such file or directory

What happened:

I installed kubectl using curl:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
```

Then as per instructions on https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/ I made kubectl executable and moved to PATH.

Then I went to https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/ and went to Installation section for linux to install minikube.
That installed minikube version: v0.28.0

See below details:

```
docker@default:/home/kubernetes$ curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube
 /usr/local/bin/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 40.8M  100 40.8M    0     0  2039k      0  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:-- 2373k
docker@default:/home/kubernetes$ minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.0
docker@default:/home/kubernetes$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 153.08 MB / 153.08 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
E0625 21:25:20.969504    6371 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path.

 Retrying.
E0625 21:25:20.975760    6371 start.go:174] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
================================================================================
An error has occurred. Would you like to opt in to sending anonymized crash
information to minikube to help prevent future errors?
To opt out of these messages, run the command:
        minikube config set WantReportErrorPrompt false
================================================================================
Please enter your response [Y/n]:
```

Expected result: 
minikube should start properly without any error.

Steps to reproduce it :

```
1. Get windows docker toolbox and install on windows 7
2. start docker quickstart terminal
3. ssh docker@192.168.99.100
4. install-kubectl
5. install minikube
6. command: start minikube
```

========================================================

UPDATE-1

As suggested in comments by @mk_sta:

I reinstalled VirtualBox latest version and then ran docker-machine command and I got same error.

```
docker@default:~$ docker-machine version 
docker-machine version 0.14.0, build 89b8332 
docker@default:~$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default 
Creating CA: /home/docker/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem 
Creating client certificate: /home/docker/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem 
Running pre-create checks... Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

I also installed kubectl binary via curl for linux.
When I tried to check its version, I got below error

```
docker@default:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-2
7T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: @KenWhite Edited title. Thanks for that suggestion

Answer (score 1):

faced similar issue on macos high sierra, stopped the processes of docker which are currently running, issue is occuring because virtualbox is not installed properly.

```
ps -ef|grep docker
sudo kill -9 <pid in above command output>
```

now i followed the below url : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/39369,

```
#!/bin/bash

unload() {
    if [ `ps -ef | grep -c VirtualBox$` -ne 0 ]
    then
            echo "VirtualBox still seems to be running. Please investigate!!"
            exit 1;
    elif [ `ps -ef | grep -c [V]ir` -gt 0 ]
    then
            echo "Stopping running processes before unloading Kernel Extensions"
            ps -ef | grep [V]ir | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
    fi
    echo "Unloading Kernel Extensions"
    kextstat | grep "org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
    kextstat | grep "org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
    kextstat | grep "org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
    kextstat | grep "org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sudo kextunload -b org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
}

load() {
    echo "Loading Kernel Extentions"
    sudo kextload "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/"
    sudo kextload "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetAdp.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/"
    sudo kextload "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetFlt.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/"
    sudo kextload "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxUSB.kext" -r "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/"
}

case "$1" in
    unload|remove)
            unload
            ;;
    load)
            load
            ;;
    *|reload)
            unload
            load
            ;;
esac
```

copy paste this script in the script-run, give 755 permissions to it. Run this script after you attempt to install virtualbox. Keep approving the kexts until the script runs cleanly:

[image]

click allow, now try to run the below command, this should successfully install virtualbox:

```
brew cask reinstall --force virtualbox;
sudo minikube start;
```

If you are still getting error:

```
sudo minikube delete;
sudo minikube start;
sudo minikube dashboard;
```

Comment: Thanks for the details however, I was facing issue on windows-7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs provided from minikube installation:

```
E0625 21:25:20.969504 6371 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks. : VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path.
```

In that case, I would recommend you to reinstall [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to the latest version on your Windows 7 machine and execute the next command as per solution given in this [post](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2608):

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

Please also do not forget to delete old minikube folder `[User folder]/.minikube` before you start with re-installation.

Comment: docker@default:~$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.14.0, build 89b8332
docker@default:~$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Creating CA: /home/docker/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem
Creating client certificate: /home/docker/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Comment: I reinstalled VirtualBox latest version and then ran docker-machine command and I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following the standard procedure of minikube installation via this [link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/). My presumption is that you have tried to install minikube entirely in boot2docker Linux shell which was running on local VirtualBox hypervisor; however, it is hard to install VirtualBox driver for minikube setup inside a virtual machine.

Comment: I tried to follow the given link. I already have restalled virtualbox, so tried to install kubectl. That was fine, but when tried to print version I saw error. Added that error in description as UPDATE-1

Comment: You can proceed by following my recommendation in previous post and install minikube on your Windows 7 machine as described (http://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/), instead of using boot2docker Linux image for that purpose.

Comment: I have dual booted my machine and installed Linux Mint 19. There I tried to install minikube and it looks fine there. Thanks for providing details but its not advisible to use minikube with windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed minikube on virtual machine HostOS : windows 7 , Guest : Antix

```
1. Disable virtualization(VT-X/AMD-v) and PA-NX in virtual machine.

2.As windows 7 doesn't have VT-X flag if it has in your case disable it.

3.sudo apt install conntrack

4.sudo minikube start --driver=none

5. Fire command : kubectl [If you get output like helper command it is installed]
```